# Why does grails URL params decoding behave differently on server vs. local

Tags: url, grails, urlencode, parameters, urldecode

Let's say I have the following entry in my grails URLMappings.groovy:

```
"/actionName/param1"(controller:'myController', action:'myAction')
```

When I call an URL where `param1` includes `+` as a special character, the URL is encoded correctly to `/actionName/my%2Bparam` for example, both in my local and in my server environment.

In my local environment - also using "prod" as the environment parameter - this is correctly resolved to  `my+param` in the controller. However in my "real" production environment (Amazon Web Service EC2 instance), the URL is resolved to "my param" which is wrong.

I have no idea what the reason for this could be. Both environments use TomCat, and as stated above I'm even using the prod environment settings in my local environment so it can't be a differing configuration between development and production.

Does anybody have an idea where I could dig deeper to identify the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Is the EC2 instance running Apache in front of Tomcat? I've had issues before with params being decoded twice, once by Apache and then again by Tomcat. From memory, I think I adjusted the configuration of the ProxyPass directive in Apache to correct it.

**EDIT:**

I found the following instructions I'd left with the source code for my app :)

Apache httpd.conf additions

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On 
ProxyTimeout 3600
```

We also upgraded apache 2.2.12+ to fix HEAD > GET rewrite bug using a startup shell script.

I also added 'nocanon' option to ProxyPass directive to stop auto decoding by mod_proxy in /etc/httpd/conf.d/cluster.conf

I think I had to do this on the server as you can't modify this using the GUI. I also have a note that says it causes they query string to be encoded. Perhaps I had to add an extra decode in my app to handle this (sorry can't remember for sure!)

Tomcat startup parameters

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
```

I think this was to get tomcat to handle slashes correctly

cheers

Lee

Comment: Sounds reasonable... I haven't found any useful discussions on this topic though, seems like this is not a common problem. I'll try to dig deeper / find the respective configuration setting.

Comment: I've now checked something different than %2B. When I put %2520 in the URL (%25 is the code for %), it is correctly resolved to %20, so I think there is no double decoding. Otherwise %20 would be decoded as well to a space. But thanks anyway! I guess the quest continues.

Comment: So is Apache running in front of Tomcat? I'd still take a look at the http.conf settings if it is. '+' is a bit of a special case I think.

Comment: I checked it and Apache is definitely running in front of Tomcat. I also found out that the JkOption ForwardURIProxy "partially re-encodes" the URL when forwarding to Tomcat and thought that changing it to ForwardURICompatUnparsed would do it (see http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/printer/apache.html), but then I saw that the jk_mod module isn't even installed on the server. Do you know if it is still used with the default even if not explicitly installed or if there must be another coordination between Apache and Tomcat then? You also mentioned the ProxyPass directive!?

Comment: Yes, ProxyPass comes from mod_proxy (I think) and it was being used (via a CloudFoundry deployment) to round-robin between a cluster of tomcats. I think it was just using HTTP proxying, not AJP like jk_mod does.

Comment: I'm using CloudFoundry deployment as well! Do you remember how you fixed the problem there? Did you add a custom tomcat configuration command upon deployment or did you edit files on the server?

Comment: @werner5471 I went and had a dig around and found a list of changes I made when deploying my app. I've added it to my original answer above. Hope it helps! I set those options via the cloud foundry GUI. You may or may not need to upgrade apache as CF might be using a newer AMI by now.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! It seems to address handling slashes, but does it also fix the problem with + signs?

Comment: @werner5471 I think the 'nocanon' option was the part that fixed the '+' signs.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [known bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6623) that has been introduced in Groovy 1.3.4 or few build versions before. It has been fixed in current version 1.3.5.

> this is correctly resolved to my+param
>   in the controller

No, the expected resolution is "my param" (with a space).
As that works at the Amazon host, you'd upgrade Grails to 1.3.5, locally.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not it. The expected resolution is "my+param" because the URL code is %2B (not %20 or +). And I'm using 1.3.5 which is also deployed on the server. So locally it's resolved correctly, and it's wrong on Amazon.

Comment: Sorry, I'd misread "%2B" as "%20". - FYI, your symptom of "%2B" not being correctly decoded to "+" has been, as well, a bug in 1.3.4, and fixed in 1.3.5 (according to my own testings). - You could use *assert "1.3.5" == grailsApplication.properties.metadata.'app.grails.version'* in your controller to make sure that 1.3.5 is in use.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However if I'm correct, when building a war file the content is always the grails version that is used locally. Since I'm sure I use 1.3.5 locally and I deploy this war file on the Amazon server, it must be 1.3.5 as well.

Comment: It's not fixed in 1.3.5 or 1.3.6. I upgraded from 1.3.4 to 1.3.6 specifically to deal with a similar server vs. local decoding problem, and my problem at that time was fixed. But now I'm facing this exact problem with an encoded + that disappears. It's as if the decoding first decodes the %xx, and then decodes the +.